# Alternative to MQL5

Tags: matlab, mql5, metatrader5

I am starting with Expert Advisors on `MetaTrader Terminal` software and I have many algorithms to use with it. These algorithms were developed in `MATLAB` using its powerfull built in functions ( e.g. `svd`, `pinv`, `fft` ). 
To test my algorithms I have some alternatives:

1. Write all the algorithms in `MQL5`.
2. Write the algorithms in `C++` and than make a `DLL` to call by `MQL5`.
3. Write the algorithms in `Python` to embed in `C` and than make a `DLL`.
4. Convert the `MATLAB` source code to `C` and than make a `DLL`.

About the problems:

1. Impracticable because `MQL5` does not have built in functions so I will have to implement one by one by hand.
2. I still did not try this, but I think it will take a long time to implement the algorithms ( I wrote some algorithms in `C` but took a good time and the result wasn't fast like `MATLAB` ).
3. I am getting a lot of errors when compiling to a `DLL` but if I compile to an executable there is no error ( this would be a good alternative since to convert `MATLAB` to `python` is quite simple and fast to do ).
4. I am trying this now, but I think there is so much work to do.

I researched about other similar pieces of software, like `MetaTrader Terminal` but I didn't found a good one.

I would like to know, if there is a simplest ( and fast ) way to embed other language in some way to `MQL5` or some alternative to my issue.

Thanks.

Comment: There are a few ways to connects _Metatrader_ (4 or 5) to Matlab. The first that comes to mind are: [Interaction between MеtaTrader 4 and MATLAB Engine](https://www.mql5.com/en/articles/1567) and [MetaTrader 5 and MATLAB Interaction](https://www.mql5.com/en/articles/44).

Answer (score 1):

### Yes, there is alternative ...    5 ) Go Distributed :

having a similar motivation for using non-**`MQL4`** code for fast & complex mathematics in external quantitative models for FX-trading, I have started to use both **`{ MATLAB | python | ... }`** and **`MetaTrader Terminal`** environments in an interconnected form of a heterogeneous distributed processing system.

**`MQL4`** part is responsible for:

1. `anAsyncFxMarketEventFLOW` processing
2. `aZmqInteractionFRAMEWORK` setup and participation in message-patterns handling
3. `anFxTradeManagementPOLICY` processing
4. `anFxTradeDetectorPolicyREQUESTOR` sending analysis `RQST`-s to remote AI/ML-predictor
5. `anFxTradeEntryPolicyEXECUTOR` processing upon remote node(s) indication(s)

**`{ MATLAB | python | ... }`** part is responsible for:

1. `aZmqInteractionFRAMEWORK` setup and participation in message-patterns handling
2. `anFxTradeDetectorPolicyPROCESSOR` receiving & processing analysis `RQST`-s to from remote `{ MQL4 | ... }` -requestor
3. `anFxTradeEntryPolicyREQUESTOR` sending trade entry requests to remote `{ MQL4 | other-platform | ... }`-market-interfacing-node(s)

### Why to start thinking in a Distributed way?

**The core advantage is in re-using the strengths** of `MATLAB` and other COTS  `AI/ML`-packages, without any need to reverse engineer the still creeping `MQL4` interfacing options ( yes, in the last few years, DLL-interfaces had several dirty hits from newer updates ( strings ceased to be strings and started to become a struct (!!!) etc. -- many man*years of pain with a code-base under maintenance, so there is some un-forgettable experience what ought be avoided ... ).

**The next advantage** is to become able to **add failure-resilience**. A distributed system can work in ( 1 + N ) protected shading.

**The next advantage** is to become able to **increase performance**. A distributed system can provide a pool of processors - be it in a **`{ SEQ | PAR }`**-mode of operations ( a pipeline-process or a parallel-form process execution ).

---

**`MATLAB`** node just joins:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% MATLAB script to setup 

zeromq-matlab
clear all;
if ~ispc
    s1 = zmq( 'subscribe', 'ipc', 'MATLAB' );   %% using IPC transport on <localhost>
else
    disp( '0MQ IPC not supported on Windows.' )
    disp( 'Setup TCP transport class instead' )
    disp( 'Setting up TCP')                     %% using TCP transport on <localhost>
    s1 = zmq( 'subscribe', 'tcp', 'localhost', 5555 );
end

recv_data1 = [];                                %% setup RECV buffer
```

This said, one can preserve strengths on each side and **avoid any form of duplications of already implemented native, high-performance tuned, libraries**, while the distributed mode of operations also adds some brand new potential benefits for **`Expert Advisor`** modus operandi.

- one may add a remote keyboard interface to an EA automation and use some custom-specific commands ( **`CLI`** )
- a fast, non-blocking, distributed remote logging
- GPU / GPU-grid computing being used from inside `MetaTrader Terminal`
- may like to [check other posts on **extending `MetaTrader Terminal` programming models**](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A3666197%20%5Bmql4%5D%20ZeroMQ)

---

### A Distributed System, on top of a Communication Framework:

[**`MATLAB`** has already available port of **`ZeroMQ`** Communication Framework](http://andyljones.tumblr.com/post/135109368968/using-matlab-with-zeromq), the same that **`MetaTrader Terminal`** has, thanks to Austin CONRAD's wrapper ( though the `MQH` is interfacing to a `ver 2.1.11` DLL, the services needed work like a charm ), so you are straight ready to use it on each side, so these types of nodes are ready to join their respective roles **in any form one can design into a truly heterogeneous distributed system**.

[image]

My recent R&D uses several instances of `python`-side processes to operate  **`AI/ML-predictor`**, **`r/KBD`**, **`r/RealTimeANALYSER`** and a centralised **`r/LOG`** services, that are actively used, over many `PUSH/PULL` + `XREQ/XREP` + `PUB/SUB` Scalable Formal Communication Patterns, from several instances of `MetaTrader Terminal`-s by their respective `MQL4`-code.

`MATLAB` functions could be re-used in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

MetaTrader 5 offers support for [OpenCL](https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/opencl) and [DirectX](https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/directx).

In 2020, Sergey Golubev published [an outline of introductory articles for OpenCL support in MetaTrader 5](https://www.mql5.com/en/forum/338240#comment_16021981), at the MQL forums. Compared to an implementation singularly in MQL, perhaps the OpenCL subsystem may provide for a more computationally optimized approach towards implementing any more relatively math- and data-intensive technical analysis methods in MT5. There's also [support for Python](https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/python_metatrader5), of course.

Though I haven't been able to work with it directly, as yet, I believe that the OpenCL support is implemented with a second programming language supplementing MQL5, mainly a programming language for OpenCL. From the examples, it looks quite similar to C. I'm sure that there must be a number of books, expanding on the topic.

In MQL5, it seems that the OpenCL programs can be provided to the OpenCL driver subsystem using literal strings in the MQL program, or via separate source files.

For more complex graphics, there's also [support for DirectX](https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/directx) as well as an API for chart objects in MetaTrader 5.

As one idea, perhaps these APIs could be of use for a port of the *heat map* indicators illustrated by John F. Ehlers, such as in Ehlers' book, *Cycle Analytics for Traders*, furthermore discussed in the [Technical Papers](https://www.mesasoftware.com/TechnicalArticles.htm) published by John F. Ehlers at the [MESA Software](https://mesasoftware.com/) Web site. These examples are implemented mainly in the TradeStation *EasyLanguage*.

Given the examples in the book and in the articles - as compared to the perhaps more common, commonly more moving-average-based and more directly price-based indicator methods, such as with Welles Wilder's ADX - most of these newer examples may be relatively math-intensive to program, using a number of trigonometric transformations for instance. Given one of the more data-intensive autocorrelation examples using "line drawing", while it may be simple enough to be implemented in MQL4, but - in at least one approach - it may sort of bog the terminal down in MQL4 with an otherwise straightforward operation on a 2x48 array of `double` typed values. I'm working on porting this, at present, as a part of a broader codebase in MQL4. Hopefully it can be ported to MQL5 and OpenCL, given at least one approach in an earlier edition of the MQL language.

For new projects, there's the documentation and the examples available?

Porting from MQL4 would be a whole other topic, LoL, ostensibly a short process though.